# What does "he's is not equal to the job" mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I know about origin, which comes from the maths symbol `≠`. But in this case it must be something else. What does it mean when someone is not equal to something?

Comment: The individual lacks the qualifications necessary to properly do the job being discussed.

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but I’m more familiar with being/not being “equal to **the task**” (as opposed to “**the job**”).  Although in most cases they probably mean the same thing (as discussed elsewhere), I think “not equal to the job” would more likely be used to explain an outright firing whereas “not equal to the task” might be less final and used to explain a reassignment of duties.

Comment: He doesn't "measure up" to the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means he is not able to do the job.  Probably the job is too hard for him.

Alternately you may say

> He is not up to the job.

or

> The job is beyond him.